# How can this question be improved?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, list-questions

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37207/how-does-time-travel-take-into-account-the-rotation-revolution-of-the-earth) was closed, for being a list question.  Then it was edited, and reopened.  At this point, one answer takes a somewhat more generalized approach to answering it, while 3 answers are 'me too' answers that have one example work and a short description.

How can the question be improved to avoid further 'me too' answers?

Comment: I'm too brain dead to offer a good **wording** at the moment so it's a comment instead of an answer, but something to the effect of "`What are the different approaches taken by SFF creators to addressing this issue`" might help?

Answer (score 1):

The question specifically asks for:

> I'm just wondering if this is something that has been addressed to any detail

So it would seem that a "me too with one example" satisfies that requirement.  One example is all that is required to be able to say "yes, it has been addressed", and some information on that example provides the detail.

To be honest, it's worded in very general terms and so as long as it retains that wording I'm not seeing how it could be improved.  As it stands it's really just a "yes/no" question at heart, and on re-reading it seems to invite discussion more than anything else.  It's really difficult to see how it could be answered in any way other than either an open-ended discussion or a list of examples.

Perhaps by focussing on one very specific example of time travel - e.g. something like the Terminator movies - and asking the question in terms of that example might make it better, but then maybe it's getting close to "too localized" territory, and in any case it's moving away from the original intent of the question.